# Creating local variable in Hive

Tags: hive

Let's assume I have a table (my_table) with four double columns A, B, C, and D. I'd like to create a new table that uses derived data from the existing table as such:

```
create table my_new_table as select A, B, C, D, A / (C + D), B / (C + D) from my_table;
```

Is there a way to define a local variable (e.g. my_var = C + D) that I could declare in the select statement and then use across the row, i.e.

```
create table my_new_table as select A, B, C, D, A / my_var, B / my_var from my_table;
```

Just wanted to know if this is feasible in Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is feasible, and here's an example of how to do it.

```
set my_var = C+D;
create table my_new_table as 
select A, B, C, D, A / ${hiveconf:my_var}, B / ${hiveconf:my_var} from my_table;
```